# how to make an auto suggestion plugin for searchbox like google's by ajax jquery

Tags: ajax, search

I'am trying to make an auto suggestion plugin, this suggest by relevance, popularity
 and change color of found-keywords, display 5 different suggestions

I'm noob, plz help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could suggest the following example to search using ajax call. Only thing is your search item should be stored in database so you can retreive the information from the database as search item

```
 $("#searchkeyWord").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Path/searchByName",
                dataType: "",
                data: {querypatam: request.term},
                success: function( data ) {

                    response( $.map( data.SearchResponse, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            id:item.id,
                            label: item.Name,
                            value: item.id
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var name_no_html=ui.item.label.replace('<b>','');
            var name_no_html=name_no_html.replace('</b>','');
            $("#searchkeyWord").val(name_no_html);
            $("#searchkeyWord_value").val(ui.item.id);
            return false;
        },
        minLength: 3  // can increase or decrease your term to be searched 
    });
```